# Getting font handle for already installed font

Tags: windows

Can anyone tell me how I get the HFONT handle to send a WM_SETFONT message? The font is calibri and should already be installed on Windows, all I can see is the add/create functions here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144821%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

the CreateFont function states it returns a handle but Im wondering why I would need to create something thats already there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing that's "there" is a set of font files in the c:\windows\fonts directory.  They contain the *outline* of the font.  You really do have to call CreateFont().  At which point Windows actually accesses the file and creates the *specific* font you ask for.  With the requested height, weight, etc.